# public IP is different than router IP?

Tags: networking

my problem is that my public IP (when I checked it on what is my IP ) is different than the IP showed in my router. this issue causes me one way communication in VoIP. So how can I fix it ?

Comment: In all likelihood: Not at all. Your provider is using Carrier Grade NAT.

Comment: Do you have just one router, or are you chaining two of them?

Answer (score 0):

Your router uses 2 IP addresses:

- One *private* address, that is used to connect to your internal LAN that usually is in the range of *192.168.X.Y*
- One *public* address, that connects the router to the ISP. It is the IP address that you find in sites as `www.whatismyip.com`.

In the middle, the router is doing NAT to translate the internal to external address.

You will need to use a [STUN server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN). It helps the UDP packets to traverse the NAT on the router.

Comment: In this case it seems to be _three_ addresses – private (LAN NAT), private (CGNAT), and public. Otherwise most routers would already show the public addresses in their web interface.